# Building an R package which uses a c code library

Tags: c, r

I want to submit a package, but when reading to R repository policies, I found that: "Source packages may not contain any form of binary executable code.". I currently have a binary executable for mac, win and Linux in `.../inst`, and the package works very fine in all os. However, I think that CRAN won't accept this. I have begun to find some info, but I am new to C and all I read is very confusing. It seems that there are several ways to carry out this and I don't know which one is the best.

My binary executable needs a specific class file in the directory, which is rendered by a function.

All my functions depend on the c library. So, what is the action I should do to get the acceptance of CRAN? ...e.g, compile with Rtools and put the executables in `.../inst`? Leave the library in `.../inst` and make a function that will do the work?

**Self-study.** Updates about the steps taken to solve the problem:

Install `Rcpp` package,

`install.packages("Rcpp")`

and install [R tools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).
Create a new package in `R studio` of type "`Package w/ Rcpp`" and select the main file of my c code library in "`Create package based on source files`".

Comment: Ask this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel, he is the author of Rcpp package!

Comment: Thank you. Before asking I will finish reading this: http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf Any comment will be helpful... to go fast ^^

Answer (score 7):

Your analysis is correct: a binary won't fly at CRAN.  So you need to make it a library. Or, rather, a package for CRAN.

That is not *as hard* as it sounds.  First off, if you wrote the binary you probably know how to reorganize the code to do

```
void main() {
     // preliminary stuff on argc/argv
     // sort our arguments
     // call main function f(a, b, c)
}
```

If you can get to that spot,  you're almost done.  Place the file doing `f(a,b,c)` into `src/`, and use (fairly simple, comparatively speaking) Rcpp code tp pass `a`, `b` and `c` to your function -- and to then get the results (a numeric vector, maybe?) back.

Start with the [Rcpp-introduction](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) vignette and take it from there.

Comment: Thank you @Dirk Eddelbuettel. One of my colleagues did the c code a long time ago, and I am not familiar with c. I've been very focused on R functions and writing good documentation because exec. binaries worked so well! I'm obviously reading your work; for the moment I understand that I should probably make minor modifications on my c code library -or translation- building another package [?]. The problem is that is a huge code (organized in 14 files) and complex (signal processing things).. the thing is that I already finished my package and now I have to deal "parsimoniously" with this.

Comment: The results are a large matrix (spectral data), a vector and a scalar.

Comment: That's good - - those are 'plain old data' types for which can in fact automate the return.

Comment: Well, what I'm doing now is to create in R-studio a C++ file and introduce the code there. I'm reading. Ok.. I'm working on it. I will update some results. Thank you, and the doc is very nice!

Comment: Good.  Read the Rcpp-introduction. Use maybe RStudio "New Project -> Package with Rcpp" to start a package. Then add one file to, say, take a matrix and double it.  Then try adding files from you wav reader. Small steps.  Check everything on the way.  Save interim snapshots.

Comment: Dirk, sorry to bother you. I think I have to transform my c code to Rcpp code right? My code depends on *.c and *.h files, and I have one central function that depends on the other 10 files approx. Should I also translate each file too? On the other hand, I've tried some of the examples (e.g. convolution) but I got errors... and a large file sample.h appears suddenly. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @fina There is no need to rewrite anything, since you can call your C functions from C++. Rcpp is used to communicate between R and the C functions.

Comment: @fina I do not understand your question. The procedure Dirk described is spot on. I only wanted to point out that you can call the C functions directly without having to translate them to C++/Rcpp.

Answer (score 4):

A single SO answer is not enough to explain all the details of interfacing R with C/C++.
Just getting C/C++ code to compile on different systems is a deep rabbit hole,
and that's what's going to be the tricky part in problems like yours.

CRAN expects all packages that need an executable to include the source code for it,
as well as whatever is necessary to configure its compilation.
The former entails that whatever library you depend on must have open source code,
and a license that's compatible with CRAN policies;
the latter entails making sure the library can be built by [R's toolchain](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).

Take for instance [`RcppParallel`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppParallel),
which essentially wraps [Intel's TBB](https://github.com/intel/tbb) for R packages to use.
It includes the latter's source code under [`src`](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppParallel/tree/master/src/tbb),
and mentions relevant copyrights and system requirements on its description
(as seen on its CRAN page).
From what I can tell,
the developers had to write a [`Makevars.in`](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppParallel/blob/master/src/Makevars.in) file to integrate it with R.

That is just one example,
and unfortunately there's no one answer that fits all cases.
Look for example at the [README for `httpuv`](https://github.com/rstudio/httpuv/tree/master/src)
(scroll down there).

I don't mean to be discouraging,
but integrating existing C/C++ libraries with R is indeed complex.
If you want to do it,
you'll have to be patient and start with the basics.
If the library you need isn't open source,
I doubt you can get your package on CRAN.
If it is, check how it is compiled as stand-alone, and go from there.

Oh and BTW, `Rcpp` is not integrating existing libraries with R,
it is essentially a package with C++ interfaces for R's C API
(and a bunch of extra functionality on top of that),
so it's not the best example for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Alexis: I disagree. "It is the best [simple] tool".  R only has a C interface, so Rcpp talks C anyway, and we happily interface C libraries all day long.  We "just" have the option of doing a little C++ as well.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel fair enough, but core Rcpp's purpose isn't to facilitate integration with existing C libraries (in my opinion). It can certainly help, but getting things to compile is still difficult.

Comment: Rcpp's mission is to extend R (more) easily. Trust me when I say that that include C libraries.  RcppGSL was one of the earlier packages -- all C on the GSL side.

Comment: My code is open source, no problem for that. I invert a lot of time doing that package, and I see that the solution is not an easy one. But I want to try. I appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: @fina if it's your code then Dirk's answer might be more applicable. That case isn't so complicated, I thought it was someone else's code.

Comment: Well, let me explain better. Is the code of the coauthor of my package. And it is a open source code.

Answer (score 1):

[Dirk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58243793/8416610) describes what you have to do: Transform your program into a library, i.e. a set of callable functions, and include that into your package. Here I want to give a very short and simplified example of how to do this second step. Note that the precise details will depend on the signature of your function(s).

Let's start with a trivial C function declared in `foo.h`, which can also be used from C++:

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    double namefunction(double x);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and defined in `foo.c`:

```c
#include "foo.h"

double namefunction(double x) {
    return x * 1.234;
}
```

In order to call this function from R, we write a wrapper function using Rcpp:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "foo.h"

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double foo(double x) {
    return namefunction(x);
}
```

All these files are to be placed in the `src` directory of an R package created with `Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton()` or the appropriate function in RStudio. After calling `Rcpp::compileAttributes()`, building and installing the package (or using `devtools::load_all()`), the function `foo` will be available:

```
> foo(34.03566)
[1] 42
```

Comment: thank you so much. I'll check this afternoon. A wrapper function is a *.R file extension? This answer looks very helpful to me.

Comment: @fina The file with the wrapper function contains C++ code and should have the extension `.cpp`.

Comment: I created these three files `foo.h`, `foo.c` and `foo.cpp` in the directory `scr` after creating a new package with `Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton()`. Then I typed in the R promnt `Rcpp::compileAttributes()`  and  `devtools::load_all()` in the main directory, and I got an error "`Error in (function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE,: System command error`". I have reinstalled Rtools, and set the path -just in case-, but the problem remains the same. The `Rcpp` package was loaded too. What I am missing?

Comment: @fina The `.c` and `.cpp` files must have different names. The way you have set it up, both will create a file `foo.o` on compilation.

Comment: Thank you another time @Ralf Stubner, but I got the same error. You can see a screenshot of the error in the question.

Comment: As I see this is not related to the files you make me create. Maybe I forgot to declare or install something?

Comment: @fina It is difficult to tell based on the information you give. For example, when it comes to compiler errors, the first error is most of the time more interesting than the last one. Anyway, the package that works for me can be found here: https://github.com/rstub/stackoverflow/tree/master/58239904

Comment: Thank you. `DONE (SO.58239904)`. I will now try my c code, with a lot of faith and hope. The problem of my last error was Rcpp, and I had to reinstall it to compile the files. What I am wondering is if any user of my package will need Rtools to run it (obviously yes). But then, they will get a message, or it will be automatically installed to their computers?

Comment: @fina Development tools like compilers (i.e. Rtools on Windows) are not automatically installed. However, when you are targeting Windows, you could build a binary package so that others won't need to have Rtools installed.

Comment: @fina You seem to have code in sub-directories. See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Compiling-in-sub_002ddirectories. It might make sense to supply a `Makefile` that compiles a static library against which you then link.

Comment: I upload to Gh the "old" `Makefile` and the new `Makevar` I self-made. In the "old" one, it seems that compilation follows an order. How can I set this in `Makevar`? For the `PKG_CPPFLAGS` and `PKG_LIBS` I copied the same from one random package (...I don't know how to use it). Is this `Makevar` file the only necessary thing to compile? Which is the next step? `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` and `devtools::load_all()`?. Thank you very much for your help,